# How to get only top row from multiple tabs into a new tab?

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

I have multiple tabs of each city which include the information of that specific city. The question is I want to fetch only the top row from each city tab into a new tab that includes city names that are unique.

Example:
I have three tabs of cities say NY, DC, and Chicago, each contains information about that particular city.
I have made a new tab (let's say the name of the tab is tab_city) with only 1 column (cities) which includes city names as NY, DC, and Chicago.
I want to fetch only the topmost row of each city from the multiple city tabs into the tab_city tab.
Is there any function/formula which does it dynamically like if I drag the formula in the tab_city, automatically the information(only the top row of each city) of other cities comes?

Thank You

PS:
If the description is biased, the below link will lead you halfway.
Visit: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sjnUThSQ8hk

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully I got the details right.

**Let's Assume the following:**

1. The sheet for each table is called with the city code. E.g. "NYC", DC", etc.
2. The table structure for the first line of each sheet is fixed and has 3 columns. (change this number as needed).
3. The sheet for the "tab_city" has in column A the name of the city (that is also the name of the sheet with the info about that city).

Then you can use the function `=INDIRECT` to do this.

**tab_city**
[image]

The formula in tab_city!B2 is:
`=INDIRECT(A2&"!A1:C1")`

- It will populate the value for B2 as well as the values of the next two columns, C2 and D2.
- If you copy the formula to the next line it will do the same for the next tab.